# Agenda in Outlook Meeting body not possible to update by receiver/attendies

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I have a request where multiple user in a Team want to update the agenda in the Meeting body/invite which They have received in outlook. By default it seem only the organiser can update the agenda and not the other attendees in the Meeting. Can someone advise if there is a workaround for this ? If its not possible in outlook or is there any Tenant setting that might be needed to adjust to allow user this fubctionality?

Comment: Only the organizer can change the agenda in Outlook.

Comment: Any work around by maybe using power automate ? Any suggestion?

Comment: Try looking at Graph API or EWS (discontinued).